# How can I change the main css for v-table?

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a structure of components as follows:

```
src
 |___assets
       |____css
             |_____main.css
 |___components
       |____info
             |_____info.vue
```

In info.vue I have a v-table with information. I have other files with v-tables too, so I have global css classes in main.css for all the v-tables.

All the css for other components are working, except for the v-table.

This is part of the css code for the v-table:

```css
v-table {
    border: 1px solid var(--black);
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

v-table.FR {
    width: 1010px;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

v-table.FR td, v-table.FR tr.C1 td {
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}
```

This is the v-table inside

```css
<v-table
      class="FR"
      cellspacing="0"
    >
      <tr>
        <th colspan="5">
          Info
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>col 1</th>
        <th>col 2</th>
        <th>col 3</th>
        <th>col 4</th>
        <th>col 5</th>
      </tr>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="C1">
          <td class="center">
            1
          </td>
          <td class="right">
            2
          </td>
          <td class="right">
            3
          </td>
          <td class="right">
            4
          </td>
          <td class="right">
            5
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </v-table>
```

In the inspector I can see some classes that are added by vuetify and I think are overriding the css properties I established in main.css

[image]

Is there a way that I can override or delete the v-theme-light and v-table--density-default classes??

For example, I want to override this property, that deforms completely the format I want to give to the table:

[image]

Comment: It's not the correct CSS selector, it's missing a period.  `v-table` is not a class selector whereas `.v-table` is.

Comment: Thank you very much @yoduh can you add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: No problem!  Answer has been added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) for selecting an element by it's class name with CSS is to prefix the class name with a period.  In your case the selector should be:

```css
.v-table {
  ...
}
```